# Htaccess: redirect from old domain to new

Tags: .htaccess

I have a olddomain.com that needs to point to newdomain.com

so if somebody tries to enter oldomain.com/whatever they get to newdomain.com

i dont wnat to exactly map old urls so just that would be ok i have tried with

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com
```

but it doent work well if i try with

```
oldomain.com/whatever
```

the url appears in the broswer:

```
newdomain.comwhatever
```

(without the /)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```